# UFW is not working in an LXC container

Tags: server, iptables, ufw, lxc

I've created an LXC container on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 using the default template.

I log into it, and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw allow 22
```

At this point, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: initcaps
[Errno 2] modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/modules.dep.bin'
ip6tables v1.4.21: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## The Fix

Update `/etc/default/ufw` so that `IPV6` is equal to `no`.

## Notes

No `ufw disable` and `ufw enable` is required before you can successfully use `ufw allow 22`.

Note that I've no plans to use IPV6, so it wasn't an issue for me turning it off.

I appreciate this is a bit of a work-around, but it suits my needs.

Comment: if you are not using ipv6, you can disable ipv6 http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190189